# Android Emulator not working ANR in com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have been testing all of my apps using a physical device so far because when I first started programming, I could not get the emulator to work. But now, I decided that it would be extremely beneficial for my work to get the emulator to work. I am using a basic hello world app in this post to eliminate any possibility of it being a result of error in my code. If someone could supply a fix to my issues that would be very much appreciated!

Here is the error message which is repeatedly outputted to Logcat:

```
2018-11-18 20:49:34.238 1409-1436/system_process E/ActivityManager: 

ANR in com.google.android.gms
    PID: 5881
    Reason: executing service com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedService
    Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
    CPU usage from 48963ms to 0ms ago (2018-11-18 20:48:43.912 to 2018-11-18 20:49:32.876):
      23% 1409/system_server: 12% user + 10% kernel / faults: 174 minor
      8.8% 2630/com.google.process.gapps: 5.5% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 503 minor
      7.6% 905/adbd: 0.9% user + 6.7% kernel / faults: 273 minor
      3.3% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 3.3% kernel
      3.2% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 3.2% kernel
      2.7% 5202/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 2.3% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 195 minor
      2.4% 2588/android.process.acore: 2.1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 33 minor
      1.4% 5550/logcat: 0.4% user + 1% kernel
      1.4% 2655/kworker/u2:0: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
      1.4% 4157/kworker/u2:3: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
      1% 866/logd: 0.2% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 1 minor
      1% 3425/com.android.systemui: 0.7% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 14 minor
      0.5% 3171/com.android.phone: 0.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 7 minor
      0.4% 5735/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
      0.3% 904/surfaceflinger: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.3% 906/zygote64: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 160 minor
      0.2% 1973/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 903/servicemanager: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 843/jbd2/vdc-8: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 911/installd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
      0% 923/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 720/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1102/hostapd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 902/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 4726/com.google.android.youtube: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 928/fingerprintd: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 5881/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 5895/dex2oat: 0% user + 0% kernel
    100% TOTAL: 63% user + 35% kernel + 0.8% softirq
    CPU usage from 4359216ms to 4359216ms ago (1970-01-01 01:00:00.000 to 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000) with 0% awake:
    0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
```

## Edit

Upon closing the emulator & opening it again. I am getting very similar messages, but for different things.
    e.g

```
    1970-01-01 01:25:07.476 2750-2768/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.voicesearch
1970-01-01 01:26:25.738 1409-1438/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 2326
1970-01-01 01:26:34.089 1409-1436/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.android.launcher3:wallpaper_chooser
    PID: 2920
    Reason: executing service com.android.launcher3/.dynamicui.ColorExtractionService
    Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
    CPU usage from 24202ms to 0ms ago (1970-01-01 01:26:03.716 to 1970-01-01 01:26:27.918):
      43% 2794/zygote64: 39% user + 4.6% kernel / faults: 1630 minor 19 major
      21% 1409/system_server: 14% user + 7.1% kernel / faults: 776 minor
      3.9% 2920/com.android.launcher3:wallpaper_chooser: 1.3% user + 2.6% kernel / faults: 3392 minor
      2.1% 905/adbd: 0.2% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 176 minor
      1.6% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
      1.4% 906/zygote64: 0.2% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 320 minor
      1.2% 868/debuggerd64: 0.2% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 30 minor
      0.7% 2630/com.google.process.gapps: 0.4% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 12 minor
      0.7% 2588/android.process.acore: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 58 minor
      0.6% 2701/com.google.android.setupwizard: 0.1% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 301 minor 1 major
      0.4% 866/logd: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 10 minor
      0.3% 843/jbd2/vdc-8: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 867/debuggerd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 92 minor
      0.3% 238/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.2% 720/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0% 2060/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.2% 2684/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.1% 746/kworker/u2:2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 2525/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 83 minor 1 major
      0% 1980/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 910/drmserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
      0% 913/media.codec: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 915/mediadrmserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
      0% 919/mediaserver: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1102/hostapd: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 1973/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 2444/com.android.settings: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
     +0% 2944/cmd: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 2955/com.google.android.deskclock: 0% user + 0% kernel
     +0% 2970/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel
    100% TOTAL: 64% user + 35% kernel + 0.2% softirq
    CPU usage from 1587917ms to 1587917ms ago (1970-01-01 01:00:00.000 to 1970-01-01 01:00:00.000) with 0% awake:
    0% TOTAL: 0% user + 0% kernel
2018-11-18 19:53:48.371 1409-1439/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2018-11-18 19:53:48.389 1409-1439/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!
-Pi Net

Comment: I literally just created a new android app and named it emulatorTesting and ran the app on a google pixel phone emulator

Comment: Wow. Never had an ANR in such a simple app in the emulator, before. You might check the Gradle and see if anything is there what you do not expect. Wish I could help more. Good Luck.

Comment: I have a really bad computer. It will overheat a very simple task, is it possible that it's completely impossible to do it because of this?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I have the same problem but for a much much complex app  ... any solution?